# Alterar posição do botão de próximo do Carousel Bootstrap

Tags: html, css3, bootstrap-3, carousel

Ao diminuir o tamanho do slide apareceu o seguinte problema: O posicionamento do botão de "next" está afastado do slide, como na imagem abaixo. Quero que ela fique no extremo lado da imagem, da mesma forma que o botão do lado esquerdo está. Porém todas as tentativas que fiz não resolveu.

[image: Botão de Next - Carousel Boostrap]

HTML:

```
<div id="carousel-cafe" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div id="div-fig-cafe" class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <figure class="item active">
            <img src="img/teste1.jpg" alt="Imagem 1">
            <figcaption class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Teste 1</p>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>               
        <figure class="item">
            <img src="img/teste2.jpg" alt="Imagem 2">
            <figcaption class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Teste 2</p>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>

    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-cafe" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>

    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-cafe" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#div-fig-cafe {
    width: 70%; /*Caso eu retire essa config, o botão se ajusta perfeitamente, porém o tamanho do slide aumenta muito*/
}
```

Comment: o slide é responsivo então ficara com a largura total do espaço disponivel, tente colocar o slide dentro de um container ou dentro de uma coluna com tamanho que você definir...

Comment: Obrigado Rafael! Deu certo. bem simples! hehe

Comment: Coloquei a resposta por favor, marque como resolvido! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O slide é responsivo, logo, ele ocupara o espaço que tiver disponível.

Coloque o slide dentro de um container ou dentro de uma `col-`, desta maneira ele irá seguir o tamanho que você indicar o elemento "pai".